# Center UlLabel shadow

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, shadow

I can't understand why my `UILabel` shadow is being created with an `offset`.

**Code**

```
lbl.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.65)
lbl.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
lbl.layer.shadowRadius = 3
lbl.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
lbl.layer.masksToBounds = false
lbl.layer.shouldRasterize = true
```

Result:

[image]

Any suggestion how to center it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried counteracting the seemingly vertical offset by setting `lbl.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: -2.0)`, for instance?

Comment: @sschale But won't it won't be generic?